# The translation of 叩きつけてきた

Tags: translation

どんな厳しいことも容赦なく叩きつけてきたこれまでの流れから、その様子が異様なものであることを理解するのに、生徒たちもそう多くの時間を必要としなかった。

The sentence was from a light novel, and the story is about a teacher who came to the class to announce an unreasonable additional exam to her students.

**叩きつけてきた** from **叩きつける** made me confused for its meaning:

From **jisho.org**

1. to throw violently against; to slam against; to strike; to slap something onto; to dash (e.g. to the floor)​
2. to thrust at someone (e.g. a letter)

Then I found a much more relevant meaning for the translation from **dictionary.goo.ne.jp**:

**激しい勢いで差し出す**。 ( I was thinking maybe the word "**present**" here can also be translated as "**announce**".)

I wonder if my interpretation appropriate for this context.

Thank you for your kind guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the definition of jisho and goo辞書 is correct and 「**激しい勢いで差し出す。**」 matches the sentence you provide.

Your interpretation seems almost correct. But I guess basically teachers are *bidding/disciplining/educating* their students rather than just presenting/announcing additional exam to them.

So, I think the sentence probably means *"Since how difficult things had been bombarded so far, students did not need that much time to understand that the situation was unusual."*

Comment: My translation is as follow: "From the course of events so far, she would have announced any kind of difficult situation without mercy, so all the students also didn’t need too much time to understand that there was something unusual from her appearance." I tried to translate any words that I think can be translated. (I often made mistakes, since I don't know which words can be omitted)

Comment: @AmandaZhang I think the choice of the translated verb depends on what 厳しいこと stands for. If we believe you that it means "series of exams", then probably you're right. The passage you provided is totally neutral on this point, so ideally I'd like to understand more of the context (previous sentences) if in a reasonable amount.

Comment: I personally consider the words "course of events" or as you said "series of exams" are needed in the translation, as the speaker narrated that the teacher was merciless (ruthless) when she made any announcements to the students before the mentioned event. This teacher was known as someone who has no compassion to the students hardships.